# Access Form VBA - Same code for each of them

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I don't know if that's possible to create a class or a procedure to apply the same code to multiple forms.

At the moment, I have copy the same code to each of the forms, which I think doesn't make any sense (I have more than 75 forms). The code is self-explanatory, it's basically move the form with mouse events. Each form has a Label named lblTitle, and that label interact with mouse events.

All the forms are Pop-up and Modal.

The actual code is the following :

```
Dim moveFrm As Boolean
Dim xMouseDown As Long
Dim yMouseDown As Long

Private Sub lblTitle_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    moveFrm = True
    xMouseDown = X
    yMouseDown = Y
End Sub

Private Sub lblTitle_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If moveFrm Then
        Me.Move Me.WindowLeft + X - xMouseDown, Me.WindowTop + Y - yMouseDown
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblTitle_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    moveFrm = False
End Sub
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To make your procedure work with any form, pass it a form object.

```
Public Sub MoveForm(ByVal theForm As Form, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    theForm.Move theForm.WindowLeft + X - xMouseDown, theForm.WindowTop + Y - yMouseDown
End Sub
```

You still need events in each form to capture the action and trigger the method:

```
Private Sub lblTitle_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If moveFrm Then
        MoveForm Me, X, Y
    End If
End Sub
```

Herein lies a problem, every time the mouse is moved this code is running. This will be a really terrible thing for performance. YMMV.

According to this doc you can set these events to macro names in Access:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.onmousedown

Those events could then, in turn, point to a VBA procedure. I'm not sure how passing the variables from an Access Macro to the VBA procedure will work. Try it out.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you :)